# Varying column width with tkz-Tab

Tags: tkz-tab, column-width

I am trying to create a signs table using the package tkz-tab. I know how to change the width of the first column or of all the remaining columns using the options `lgt` or `espcl`on `\tkzTabInit`, but they all change at the same time. I would like to have columns with different widths. Is there a proper way to set width for individual columns? I searched the packaged manual (in French), but had not luck.

Right now, I am cheating by creating empty columns, but that is not very robust.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{t style/.style = {style = densely dashed}} 
    \tkzTabInit[lgt=4, espcl = 1.2, lw = 0.5pt, deltacl=0]{ / 0.7 , $x(x^2-5x+4)$ / 1}{ ,$0$, $1$, , $4$,}

    \tkzTabLine{,-,t,+,t,,-,,t, +,}

    %A few extra marks and labels
    \draw[fill=black] (N21) circle(2pt);
    \draw[fill=black] (N31) circle(2pt);
    \draw[fill=black] (N51) circle(2pt);
    \draw[->=stealth, line width=1.5pt] (N11) -> (N61.east) node[right=2pt] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I looked through the `tkz-tab` manual but, I didn't find other methods to enlarge a single (non-first) column out of the one you used (since the manual is in French, maybe I missed something).

However, if you want more freedom to do whatever you want, you could use a `tikz matrix` directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
A solution with a \texttt{tikz matrix}:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[%
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        draw,
        inner sep=0pt,
        nodes={align=center},
        column 1/.style={text width=11.3em},
        column 2/.style={text width=3.44em},
        column 3/.style={text width=3.44em},
        column 4/.style={text width=6.88em},
        column 5/.style={text width=3.44em},
        row 1/.style={minimum height=.7cm},
        row 2/.style={minimum height=1cm},
        ] (m) {%
        & & & & \\
        x(x^2-5x+4) & - & + & - & + \\
    };
    \draw (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-5.south east);
    \draw (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-2-1.south east);
    \foreach \i/\descr in {2/0,3/1,4/4}{%
\draw[fill=black] (m-2-\i.north east) circle (2pt);
    \draw[densely dashed] (m-2-\i.south east) -- (m-2-\i.north east) node[above=3pt] {$\descr$};
    }
    \draw[->=stealth, line width=1.5pt] (m-1-1.south east) -> (m-1-5.south east) node[right=2pt] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Your original \texttt{tkz-tab}:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{t style/.style = {style = densely dashed}} 
    \tkzTabInit[lgt=4, espcl = 1.2, lw = 0.5pt, deltacl=0]{ / 0.7 , $x(x^2-5x+4)$ / 1}{ ,$0$, $1$, , $4$,}

    \tkzTabLine{,-,t,+,t,,-,,t, +,}

    %A few extra marks and labels
    \draw[fill=black] (N21) circle(2pt);
    \draw[fill=black] (N31) circle(2pt);
    \draw[fill=black] (N51) circle(2pt);
    \draw[->=stealth, line width=1.5pt] (N11) -> (N61.east) node[right=2pt] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]